# Calculating eigenvalues and solving inequalities with parameters

Tags: equation-solving, eigenvalues, parameters, findinstance

I would like to calculate b in terms of c and a, in order to satisfy the following conditions:

```
x1 = 1/2 * (c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 a b]);

y1 = 1/(2 a)*(-c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 a b]);

z1 = 1/(2 a)*(c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 a b]);

x2 = 1/2 * (c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 a b]);

y2 = 1/(2 a)*(-c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 a b]);

z2 =  1/(2 a)*(c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 a b]);

{λ1, λ2, λ3} = 
  Eigenvalues[{{0, -1, -1}, {1, a, 0}, {z1, 0, x1 - c}}];

{λ4, λ5, λ6} = 
  Eigenvalues[{{0, -1, -1}, {1, a, 0}, {z2, 0, x2 - c}}];

FindInstance[
 Re[λ1] > 1 &&  Re[λ2] < 1 && Re[λ3] < 1 && 
  c^2 - 4 a b > 0 && 0 < a < Sqrt[2] && Re[λ4] > 1 &&  
  Re[λ5] > 1 && Re[λ6] > 1, {c, b, a}]
```

One of the real part of eigenvalues of the set of first three lambdas has always to be > 1 whereas the others lambdas of that set has to be <1.

Unfortunately, Mathematica tells me that the methods used in the Solve function are insufficient... So, I decided to use Findinstance and satisfy myself with fixed values of a,b and c. The problem is that even when I use Findinstance I cannot set the conditions I need. Mathematica tells me again that the methods used in the Findinstance function are insufficient. It works only when I set all the real parts of all the eigenvalues smaller than 1 :

```
FindInstance[
 Re[λ1] < 1 &&  Re[λ2] < 1 && Re[λ3] < 1 && 
  c^2 - 4 a b > 0 && 0 < a < Sqrt[2], {c, b, a}]
```

Do you have any idea of how can I get around this problem ?

Comment: I threw a million `a=RandomReal[{0,Sqrt[2]}];{b,c}=RandomReal[{-10,10},2]` at it and did not find one that satisfied your first `Findinstance` condition. If you had any better bounds on b,c then that might find a solution. I also tried `a=RandomReal[{0,Sqrt[2]}]` and then asked `FindInstance` to look for b,c, also no success.

Comment: You don't stipulate that `{a, b, c}` are real. If that is not a requirement, then `sol = FindInstance[(Min @@ Re[{\[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3}]) < 1 && RankedMin[Re@{\[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3}, 2] < 1 && (Max @@ Re[{\[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3}]) > 1, {a, b, c}][[1]]` gives complex values for `{a, b, c}` and two eigenvalues with real part less than one and one eigenvalue with real part greater than one.